# OCAML: Difference between let func a x = (a x);; and let func a x = ((fun a -> a) x);;?

Tags: function, parameters, ocaml

I'm a little stuck on this assignment for OCAML. I'm trying to pass in a function and a value as a parameter into another function. For example, I have function called test that takes in (fun x -> x+x) and 3 as parameters. The function test should output 6, since 3 + 3 = 6. I know I can achieve something similar this by completing:

```
let func x = x + x;;

let a = func;;

let test a x = (a x);;
```

This way when I input, test a 5, I will get 10.

But when I change the statement to this, I get only the value I placed in for x. How do I get the (fun a -> a) to take in the value x?

`let test a x = ((fun a -> a) x);;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fun a -> a` is an anonymous identity function, it will always return its parameter. You could say:

```
let id = fun a -> a;;
id 3;;
  => 3
id (fun x -> x + x);;
  => (fun x -> x + x)
```

Note that in your

```
let test a x = ((fun a -> a) x);;
```

the first `a` and the other two `a`s are different variables. The first one is never used again later. You can rewrite this line for easier understanding as:

```
let test a x = ((fun b -> b) x);;
```

> How do I get the (fun a -> a) to take in the value x?

You are, and that's the problem. You're feeding your `x` to an identity function, and getting `x` back. What you want to do is feed the `x` to your `a` function, and that's what you did in your first attempt:

```
let func x = x + x;;
let test a x = a x;;
test func 3;;
  => 6
```

Answer (score 1):

With functional languages in simple cases it is often helpful to write the expression in a form similar to lambda calculus and do the reductions manually (noting which reductions you are using). You can still use OCaml syntax as a simplified version of lambda calculus

So in the case of your example this would become:

```
   let test a x = ((fun a -> a ) x);;
=> let test a x = ((fun b -> b ) x);; (* Variable renamed (alpha equivalence) *)
=> let test a y = ((fun b -> b ) y);; (* Variable renamed (alpha equivalence) *)

   let func x = x + x;;
```

Note that these steps only serve to make sure, that we will later on have no variables with the same name, referring to different values. These steps can be left out, but I personally like working with unique variables much better.

```
   test func 5
=> test (fun x -> x + x) 5 (* Variable func inserted (beta reduction) *)
=> (fun a y -> ((fun b -> b) y) (fun x -> x + x) 5 (* Variable test inserted *)
=> (fun y -> (fun b -> b) y) 5 (* Variable a inserted *)
=> ((fun b -> b) 5 (* Variable y inserted *)
=> 5 (* Variable b inserted *)
```

The final result is `5`. Attempting this at first will seem very unusual and hard, but get's easier very fast. If you do something like this a couple of time you will get much better at understanding common functional patterns and reasoning about your program structure.

Have a look at [this article](http://www.tcrueger.de/doku.php/science/papers/dyn_prog) for more examples on this.

Also note, that with a little more effort, this works backward as well. Although this usually is not as helpful as doing it in the same direction as the compiler.